# Adding a char to beginning and end of a word in VIM

Tags: vim

'Enveloping' a word or a string in a given character is one of my most executed actions in VIM.

Most common char combinations (added at beginning and end, respectively): <>, (), '', "", **, __,--, etc...

Is there a native way of doing this in VIM? If not, how could we set up a macro for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most "native" way to *surround* a word with a given pair of characters is to:

1. change the word with `ciw` (the word is put into register `"` by default),
2. insert the opening character,
3. insert the content of register `"` with `<C-r>"`,
4. insert the closing character,
5. go back to normal mode with `<Esc>`.

In short:

```
ciw(<C-r>")<Esc>
```

This is the most efficient you can get without making custom mappings or installing plugins like [Surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) or [Sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich).

Comment: Perfect. I was actually looking for a solution like Surround, but you also explained the native way of doing it which is not too bad. 
Care to explain how the change command works with ciw? I'd prefer to put it in a more 'accessible' register if possible.

Comment: Register `"` is the default register for every command that deals with registers so `ciw` means "cut the current word into register `"` and enter insert mode". If you want to cut into a specific register, you have to specify it, like so: `"aciw`, which means "cut the current word into register `a` and enter insert mode".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function abstracting all the chang inner word:

```
if !exists('*AddSingleQuotes')
    function! AddSingleQuotes()
        exec "normal! ciw''\<Esc>P"
    endfunction
endif
nmap <Leader>q :call AddSingleQuotes()<CR>
```

And also modify to add double quotes:

```
if !exists('*AddDoubleQuotes')
    function! AddDoubleQuotes()
        exec "normal! ciw\"\"\<Esc>P"
    endfunction
endif
nmap <Leader>q :call AddDoubleQuotes()<CR>
```

NOTE: the `if !exists` part ensures vim will not load the function more than once, even if you reload your vimrc.